# Moving from http to https - redirect via htaccess file

Tags: magento-1.8, php, .htaccess

All my urls were unsecured and was indexed by google like that.

Now I'm planning to secure all my pages with https

But when the old urls show up on google search they automatically resolve to the secure base url

for example : old url >> http://www.example.com/cameras   as indexed and cached by google.

Now when you click on the url it goes to https://www.example.com instead of **https://www.example.com/camera**

How do I get the old http url to redirect to the https url without it going to the base url?

Comment: you should just set your insecure url to https.

Comment: @ReidBlomquist that's the problem.  Setting magento's insecure url to https would mean any requests (from google) to http are redirected to homepage on https instead of where they should go.

Answer (score 6):

The following rewrite rule should forward all non-https requests to the corresponding page via https with a 301 redirect.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

Answer (score 4):

I got this from apache wiki https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteHTTPToHTTPS

```
This will enable the Rewrite capabilities
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on

This checks to make sure the connection is not already HTTPS
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
```